# Attach PDF file to email with DOMPDF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm using my MyEmail model to attach a PDF file to it. The mail gets sent with all the data I want and a PDF gets attached but it is empty, how can I import my layout and data into the PDF if I attach?

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Course;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;

class MyEmail extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    public $course;
    private $pdf;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data, Course $course) {
        $this->course = $course;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build() {
        return $this->subject('Thanks')->view('emails.my_email')->attachData($this->pdf, 'my_pdf.pdf')->with(['data' => $this->data, 'course' => $this->course]);
    }
}
```

Here's the function to send the email my controller:

```
public function sendMail(Request $request) {

    $data = array(
        'first_name'        => $request->first_name,
        'last_name'         => $request->last_name,
        'id'                => $request->id,
        'course_id'         => $request->course_id,
    );

    $resultJson = $this->validateRecaptcha($request);

    $course= Course::where('id', $data['course_id'])->first();

    if($resultJson->success != true) :
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'success']);
    else :
        \Mail::to($request->email)
             ->cc('my@*******')
             ->queue(
            new Mail\MyEmail($data, $course)
        );
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Success!']);
    endif;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF also requires a view, like so:

```
// creating the pfd:
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.multiple_pages', [
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            'title' => $this->options->get('documentName'),
        ]);
```

Where the view looks like this:

```
<?php

$imgPath = public_path('store/assets/images/new_logo.png');
$img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgPath));
?>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <title>{{ $title ?? 'document' }}</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>
    @php
        include(public_path('/css/pdf/multiple_pages.css'))
    @endphp

    div.page {
        background-image: url("data:image/png;base64, {{ $img }}");
    }
</style>
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <div class="page">
        {!! html_entity_decode($page) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

So i recommend first creating the PDF, and only then attaching it to the email

Keep in mind this is very specific to our own use case and you will need to modify this.

Comment: Could you tell me where i need to place the code for creating the PDF? I already have a view, i'm struggling to find where i need to place the code to load the view.

Comment: @ElKlo Well ideally you create the PDF somewhere before you send the mail. How are you creating the PDF now, and where?

Comment: I guess nowhere then. I would like to do this in my model but i'm guessing the controller would be a better place for this. Would it be better to place the code to attach the date in my method/controller instead of my model?

Comment: Yes, I would handle these sort of things in Controllers.

Comment: Thanks, back to the drawing board it is then. :)

Comment: Well good luck, hope you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package, you can simply use [loadView()](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using) function, that takes your `.blade` file and the data you want. Inside that blade, you will generate PDF layout and inject your variables. Simple example would be something like this:

```
$name = 'John';
$pdf = PDF::loadView('your_view', $name);
```

You can now use this `$name` variable in your pdf .blade file:

```
<h1>Hi {{name}}</h1>
```

After you generate the pdf with desired layout and data, you can attach it to Mail class like this:

```
->attachData($pdf->output(), 'your_file_name');
```